# Android java generate Integer value

Tags: java, android, sqlite

i just want a Integer Value never duplicate in future i used it as temporary `id` in sqlite until get new id from `mysql` now what i used its

`long temp_id = System.currentTimeMillis();`

but when i want to add it to sqlite it must be an Integer so i convert it to int
with

```
int temp idx = temp_id.intValue();
```

after i convert it to int  did its possible to duplicate in future ?
if its might duplicated any other idea for generate id never duplicate

Comment: [Monotonically increasing time in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/434369/608639), [Will System.currentTimeMillis always return a value >= previous calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2978598/608639), [Generate monotonically increasing integers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8876255/608639), [Generating monotonically increasing integers (max 64bit)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36396928/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1):

either use a long as an id or simply let sqlite manage generating the ids for you which is the recommended way since it's both simpler and thread-safe (will never generate duplicate ids even when accessed from multiple threads)